# Installing python package variants with conda/pip on MacOS

Tags: macos, python, macports, pip, anaconda

I currently have installed many python packages with specific variants. 
For example, I'm using the gcc5 build of scipy.
I've done this using macports, where it is as simple as:

```
port install py35-scipy+gcc5
```

Is there a way to specify such variants using conda or pip?

Inversely, perhaps it possible to install variants using macports to python in a conda env?

Thanks, Brett.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could specify a different CC before installing the package with `pip`. It'd probably be wiser to do so under a virtualenv instead of trying to do it with the system Python (and risking maiming it beyond salvation).

That way, you can use MacPorts to have a number of different Python interpreters compiled with different compilers installed separately.

You can also use https://github.com/collective/buildout.python as an option to have a wider selection of Python environments finely tuned to your desired settings.